# In Yii how to display image as output whose path is stored in database

Tags: php, database, image, yii

I am creating a project in Yii. I am having table as `Dnymedia` with fields as,

> **Dnymedia**
>
> -mediaId
>
> -mediaPath
>
> -contentTitleId

Suppose I have media path stored as="*`F:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures`*"

How do I display this image as output? I don't need to display it in view. I just want to display the image as output of the controller's action in Yii.

Comment: if you got your answer please accept it, or  let me know if any question

Answer (score 1):

instead of read file use file_get_contents

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents('F:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample.jpg');
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me.Please check it.

public function actionTest()
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        readfile('http://localhost/myAppetite/images/bodyBg.jpg');
         die;
    }
```

Comment: Sir i had tried as above. But its not displaying image,just thumbnail is displayed.....